# ValueError with statsmodels OLS

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a clustered linear regression with statsmodels:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
mod = smf.OLS("C(cured) ~ Loan_term + Loan_Amount + Loan_APR + Loan_Term + Client_Age + Total_Income", data=df)
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (17314,2). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (eg. bool or str).
```

Tried the same thing with less variables and nothing. The dependent variable is a dummy, so I put it as categorical, which I thing is okay, but anyways I tried it without it and the same error appears.
I really don't know what this error is refering to. Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your exog is a string or object. You need to ensure that it is numeric to prevent patsy from interpreting it as a categorical varia le which is then converted to a set of dummies.

Comment: Your endog or your exog?